# Cathodic protection for cars

Tags: electrons

Does cathodic protection work for cars if we attach a block of zinc to iron car chassis and connect car body to earth while parked in a garage?

Comment: Which metal(s) are you looking to protect, and is rust really an issue in cars anymore?

Comment: Iron. Clarified in question.

Comment: Since my 1968 VW Bug, I haven’t had any rust issues on a car.

Comment: Mine is a `Made in U.K.` 2011 Mini Cooper chassis

Answer (score 1):

Corrosion of steel ("iron") in car bodies is indeed a large problem, especially in coastal communities where salt spray is present and in inland communities where salt is used to de-ice the roads in wintertime. As long as steel alloys are the material of choice for car bodies and frames, rusting will continue to be a big deal.

Note that if you use zinc, then you do not require the ground connection as the corrosion circuit then consists of the chunk of zinc in direct contact with the iron frame & bodywork.

The effectiveness of this method is increased by using lots of smaller zinc chunks spread out from one another and in the limit of "smallness", the best solution by far is a coating of zinc all over the iron. This is called *galvanization* and is commonly used on iron plumbing pipes, metal fences, water tanks, buckets and so forth to prevent corrosion.

The reason it is not commonly used to rustproof cars is that car bodies are assembled by electric resistance welding, and if the welded panels have a zinc coating on them, it spoils the quality of the weld.

(Instead, it is possible to get some galvanic protection for cars by applying a relatively thick layer of a zinc-rich paint to the underbody of the car.)